# Can I optimize this jQuery 'toggle' image source function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

I have this functionality witch i am not sure is the best. It is actually working.  I'm asking because i couldn't find any 'copy-paste' solution over the net so i wrote this. There no need to suggest other CSS solutions, i am stuck with the `<a href><img>text</a>` structure and i am UNABLE to write .css (all this because of back-end coding restrictions/ ' *they are overwhelmed : lol* ' )

javascript (an easy way to let the client build his own icon set [stuck with .png]) :

```
$(".list-habiliy").on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            $('img.icone', this).attr("src",$('img.icone', this).attr("src").replace('.png', '-o.png'));
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            $('img.icone', this).attr("src",$('img.icone', this).attr("src").replace('-o.png', '.png'));
        }
    },"a");
```

html (the list of `<a>` can come up to 30 elements) :

```
<div class="list-habiliy">
    <a href="some-link1.link"><img class="icone" src="/path/to/default/icons/icon-24px-icon-name1.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" />Some text1</a>
    <a href="some-link2.link"><img class="icone" src="/path/to/default/icons/icon-24px-icon-name2.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" />Some tex2t</a>
    <a href="some-link3.link"><img class="icone" src="/path/to/default/icons/icon-24px-icon-name3.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" />Some text3</a>
    <a href="some-link4.link"><img class="icone" src="/path/to/default/icons/icon-24px-icon-name4.png" alt="" width="24" height="24" />Some text4</a>
</div>
```

The goal of the function is to replace the icon `<img>` from within an `<a>` by adding/removing **'-o'** text from image source. I'm wondering, should i use the .each(), the hover() for performance reason ?

jsFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/5dpaA/

**Is this the best way to do it ?**

Thanks for all your advices.

**[Finaly]:**

Explained by user @Xotic750 [accepted answer] (Instead of wrapping this in jquery we use the event attribute and directly access the elements using javascript, we also don't perform any further jquery searches..)

This was somehow the only optimisation i could make.

**thanks** to user @codelio [i can't accept 2 answers] for is shortened code writing :

```
$(".list-habiliy a").on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        var elm=e.delegateTarget.firstChild;
        elm.src=elm.src.replace('.png','-o.png');
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        var elm=e.delegateTarget.firstChild;
        elm.src=elm.src.replace('-o.png','.png');
    }
});
```

Comment: Look into jQuery hover, which I think is more elegant.

Comment: @rontornambe `jQuery.hover()` is just a shorthand for the code above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @Xotic750 Hi, i just dont get why you try to redirect me (us?) to the 'about' page ? Is my situation 'too localized' or something not relevant to StackOverflow, off topic or not a real question ?

Comment: Because after 6 answers and nearly 2 weeks, you may have found one of them useful, or even the answer. Perhaps you found another way that you now believe to be best. If you found another way, then it would be good to post your answer and, hey, you can even accept your own answer. Otherwise, this question starts to look like "not a real question". I just wanted to give you some feedback, far too many questions get asked on SO and then the OP never comes back to them. Some of the first lines in about: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site", "This site is all about getting answers."

Comment: Thanks @Xotic750, i get the point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution, uses [jquery event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), so only 1 event handler (well 2, one for `mounseenter` and one for `mouseleave`) attached to `list-habiliy`, if you had multiple such structures then you could attach it to `document,body` and change the selectors to `list-habiliy a,img`. Instead of wrapping `this` in jquery we use the `event` attribute and directly access the elements using javascript, we also don't perform any further jquery searches as we are now assuming that your html pattern does not deviate from that which you have stated. Still, would be pretty difficult to measure it's improvement as it is a user fired event, but it should be faster than your jquery only methods.

HTML

```
<div class="list-habiliy">
    <a href="some-link1.link"><img class="icone" src="http://placehold.it/64x64/&text=.png1" alt="" width="64" height="64" />Some text1</a>
    <a href="some-link2.link"><img class="icone" src="http://placehold.it/64x64/&text=.png2" alt="" width="64" height="64" />Some tex2t</a>
    <a href="some-link3.link"><img class="icone" src="http://placehold.it/64x64/&text=.png3" alt="" width="64" height="64" />Some text3</a>
    <a href="some-link4.link"><img class="icone" src="http://placehold.it/64x64/&text=.png4" alt="" width="64" height="64" />Some text4</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".list-habiliy").on("mouseenter", "a,img", function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target;

    if (target.nodeName === "IMG") {
        target.src = target.src.replace('.png', '-o.png');
    } else {
        target.firstChild.src = target.firstChild.src.replace('.png', '-o.png');
    }
}).on("mouseleave", "a,img", function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target;

    if (target.nodeName === "IMG") {
        target.src = target.src.replace('-o.png', '.png');
    } else {
        target.firstChild.src = target.firstChild.src.replace('-o.png', '.png');
    }
})
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/g9BpR/)

Comment: Isn't using 'event' has for a function(event) buggy (internetExploser) and to be avoided [it's a javascript reserved word]??

Comment: It's not a reserved word in javascript but it is a global variable name in at least some versions of internet explorer. I usually write "evt", don't know why I didn't this time. I never use IE,so it's no issue for me, but I will change it to avoid any possible issue. It's funny because jquery use it in many of their examples on their website. e.g. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I don't use IE either .. but 80% of our clients do. Thanks for your Edit and your consideration on my request. BTW, jQuery is NOT perfect, nor any framework (html, js, css) i've seen so far.

Comment: +1 ... event attribute and directly access the elements using javascript, we also don't perform any further jquery searches as we are now assuming that your html pattern ..

Answer (score 1):

this will allways find the hovered child which is your img, and it's fast!

```
$(".list-habiliy a").on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        //faster is not possible!
        var elm=e.delegateTarget.firstChild, src=elm.src.replace('.png','-o.png');
        elm.src=src;
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        //same a bit jQuery stylish
        var elm=e.delegateTarget.firstChild, src=elm.src;
        $(elm).attr('src',src.replace('-o.png','.png'));
    }
});
```

sorry there is a shorter one. :)

```
$(".list-habiliy a").on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
        var elm=e.delegateTarget.firstChild;
        elm.src=elm.src.replace('.png','-o.png');
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        var elm=e.delegateTarget.firstChild;
        elm.src=elm.src.replace('-o.png','.png');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it works perfectly, and I couldn't say using `.hover()` will have any performance benefits and `.each()` is unnecessary. In fact:

> Calling $(selector).hover(handlerInOut) is shorthand for:
>   $(selector).on("mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut);

Comment: If i understand : using .hover() is only 'beautiful' but does not improve performance ?

Comment: @MilchePatern there is no performance benefit of using `.hover()` - it will execute `.on()` in the end anyway so it'll actually be marginally slower but such speed issues are negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably store the `$('img.icone', this)` query in a variable so that it's not doing two queries inside each of the `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` functions.

It also increases readability and reduces potential problems should this be cut/pasted onto other areas:

```
$(".list-habiliy").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var imgIcon = $('img.icone', this);
        imgIcon.attr("src", imgIcon.attr("src").replace('.png', '-o.png'));
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var imgIcon = $('img.icone', this);
        imgIcon.attr("src", imgIcon.attr("src").replace('-o.png', '.png'));
    }
}, "a");
```

**JS Fiddle demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5dpaA/3/

Answer (score 0):

Hover is implemented like this (as seen [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event-alias.js#L14)):

```
hover: function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
    return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
}
```

So no performance here. Avoiding delegation would create a lot of handlers instead.

What you can actually do is add something like this at the end of your html:

```
<div id="hidden-img">
  <img class="icone" src="http://placehold.it/64x64/&text=-o.png1" alt="" width="64" height="64" />
  <img class="icone" src="http://placehold.it/64x64/&text=-o.png2" alt="" width="64" height="64" />
  <img class="icone" src="http://placehold.it/64x64/&text=-o.png3" alt="" width="64" height="64" />
  <img class="icone" src="http://placehold.it/64x64/&text=-o.png4" alt="" width="64" height="64" />
</div>
```

And add some CSS:

```
#hidden-img {
    margin-left: -9999px;
}
```

I think it's Opera that won't load images if they're hidden.